# аналитика данных при построении иерархии

Tags: python, pandas

Решаю такую задачу:

В упрощенном виде: есть таблица следующего вида

| таб номер подч | подчиненный | таб номер рук | руководитель |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | Ген. дер. | 123344456 | Вице-президент |
| 113213 | Гл. экономист | 112233 | Ген. дер. |
| 114213 | специалист | 112233 | Ген. дер. |
| 212233 | Слесарь | 12334 | Мастер |
| 353213 | Электрик | 12334 | Мастер |
| 12334 | Мастер | 45678 | Нач. цеха 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Всего записей в таблице порядка 117 тыс. строк.

Так же есть таблица с расчетными показателями, наподобие этой (здесь показал именно структуру и наполнение таблицы, без отображения и пояснения сути значений в ней):

| таб номер сотрудника | причина отсутствия | число отгулов |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | отпуск | 1 |
| 112233 | # | 0 |
| 123344456 | больничный | 0 |
| 113213 | обследование | 2 |
| 113213 | # | 0 |
| 113213 | прогул | 1 |
| 12334 | отпуск | 1 |
| 12334 | # | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Мне необходимо вывести новую таблицу, в которой будут отражены только руководители и статистика по их команде с учетом самого руководителя. Команда - это подчиненные руководители и их сотрудники по иерархии вниз. То есть, для вице-президента должно отражаться количество подчиненных 4 (Вице-президент, Ген. дер., Гл. экономист, специалист), число отгулов 4.
Примерно так:

| Руководитель | количество подчиненных | число отгулов по команде |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123344456 | 4 | 4 |
| 112233 | 3 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Уровень подчиненности для самих подчиненных я определяю следующим образом, используя такой код на Python:

```
# Функция для определения верхнеур. подчиненности
def find_top_leader(row):
    leaders = []
    while row['таб номер рук'] in df['таб номер подч'].values:
        row = df[df['таб номер подч'] == row['таб номер рук']].iloc[0]
        leaders.append(row['руководитель'])
    return leaders  

# Применяю функцию к каждой строке
df['верхнеур. подчиненность'] = df.apply(find_top_leader, axis=1)

# Создаю столбец с кортежами уровней подчиненности
df['уровни подчиненности'] = df['верхнеур. подчиненность'].apply(tuple)

# Разделяю кортежи на отдельные столбцы
df = pd.concat([df, df['уровни подчиненности'].apply(pd.Series).rename(lambda x: f'Уровень {x+1}', axis=1)], axis=1)
```

В итоге подчиненность с определением сотрудника и его вышестоящих руководителей выглядит так:

| таб номер подч | подчиненный | таб номер рук | руководитель | верхнеур. подчиненность |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112233 | Ген. дер. | 123344456 | Вице-президент | Вице-президент |
| 113213 | Гл. экономист | 112233 | Ген. дер. | Вице-президент |
| 114213 | специалист | 112233 | Ген. дер. | Вице-президент |
| 212233 | Слесарь | 12334 | Мастер | Нач. цеха 1 |
| 353213 | Электрик | 12334 | Мастер | Нач. цеха 1 |
| 12334 | Мастер | 45678 | Нач. цеха 1 | Нач. цеха 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

и т.д.

Но у меня никак не выходит построить такую же таблицу только для руководителей с аккумулированием статистики по подчиненной команде. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Что в итоге то нужно получить? Скорее всего подойдёт что-то типа `df.groupby('таб номер рук')...`

Comment: вам нужно сначала фактически выстроить граф с цепочками от высшего руководителя до подчиненного. а потом по нему уже считать. граф, скорее всего можно выстроить с помощью `networkx `, получить последовательные списки и суммировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то решение сводится к построению цепочек от руководителя к подчиненному (с помощью графа, например), а затем к элементарному подсчету нужных значений:

```
import networkx 
from networkx.algorithms.components.connected import connected_components
import pandas as pd

l = pd.Series(zip(df["таб номер подч"], df["таб номер рук"])).values

def to_graph(l):
    G = networkx.Graph()
    for part in l:
        G.add_nodes_from(part)
        G.add_edges_from(to_edges(part))
    return G

chains = to_graph(l)
chains = list(connected_components(chains))
print(chains)
```

выводим для наглядности список с цепочками:

```
[{123344456, 112233, 113213, 114213}, {212233, 45678, 353213, 12334}]
```

далее локатором выбираем нужные позиции из датафрейма

```
for chain in chains:
    print(df.loc[df["таб номер подч"].isin(chain)])
```

получим датафреймы с нужными цепочками:

```
   таб номер подч    подчиненный  таб номер рук    руководитель
0          112233      Ген. дер.      123344456  Вице-президент
1          113213  Гл. экономист         112233       Ген. дер.
2          114213     специалист         112233       Ген. дер.
   таб номер подч подчиненный  таб номер рук руководитель
3          212233     Слесарь          12334       Мастер
4          353213    Электрик          12334       Мастер
5           12334      Мастер          45678  Нач. цеха 1
```

ну а дальше - получить данные из второй таблицы по табельным номерам первой.